# how do I make all kinds of grids invisible in echart?

Tags: javascript, echarts

[image]

There are some horizontal lines in the background and I need remove it. I go to the `grid` section in the document, but I did not find anything related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be intuitive, but `grid` is not about the 'grid' in the background, it's rather for positionning your chart(s) in a grid system.

The grid in the background is formed by `xAxis` and `yAxis` `splitLine` parameter. Horizontal lines are from [yAxis splitLine](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.splitLine) and vertical ones are from [xAxis splitLine](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.splitLine). You can personalise it as you want and you can show/hide it as well, using :

```js
yAxis: { 
   ... // Your yAxis options
   splitLine: {show: false} 
}
```